# git merge parent branch in child branch not working

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have parent branch A and child branch B.
There were few commits in A.

I tried below commands to update my B with A.

```
git pull origin A
```

then

```
git checkout A
git pull
```

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

For first command I got merge conflicts which i resolved and pushed my changes.
But all of the changes of A was not getting reflected in B.

for second and third command I tried and got result as
`Already up to date`.

How to update B with all changes of A

Comment: `git merge A` after `git checkout B` was the right command to run. Try `git log --graph --format=oneline --all --decorate` to visualize your commit graph (or any other graphic git log tool, the important being asking it to show either all branches, or at least A and B). It should hopefully be clear why the `Already up to date` message is shown.

Comment: Question: when you did that first `git pull origin A`, where you on A or on B at the time? If you were on branch B at the time, then that would have already merged A into B, which is why the later `git merge A` didn't need to do anything.

Comment: Side note but worth remembering and thinking about: in Git, branches do not have *parent branches*. In fact, branches don't really mean anything at all. What matters in Git are *commits*. Commits have parent commits, and we can try to use that to pretend that branches have parent branches, but it ends up falling apart eventually. Stick with *commits* to avoid falling into traps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Your first operation completed the merge you are still trying to do in the last operation.

**Details**

To understand what's going on, let's replace `git pull` by its equivalent two step commands: each time you run `git pull`, what you're really doing is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

So, in step 1, you effectively did:

```
git fetch origin
git merge A  #(almost, see below)
```

Assuming you were on branch B at the time, the conflicts your resolved and committed merged A into B.

(#almost: it actually does `git merge origin/A`, but creates a default commit message saying "merge A" rather than "merge origin/A". In your case, step 2 confirms A was already up to date, so this detail would have made no difference)

In step 2, you effectively did

```
git checkout A
git fetch
git merge
```

Now by default that `git fetch` fetches from `origin`, which you'd already done in step 1. And that `git merge` saying `Already up to date` just means that your A branch was already up to date with origin at the time, since the default is to merge `origin/<my-current-branch>` into `<my-current-branch>` when you run `git merge` (or `git pull`) without an argument.

In step 3, you just tried to redo the merge you have already completed in step 1:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

so it's no surprised B is already up to date with respect to A.

**Inspecting your commit graph**

When I'm trying to figure out what's going on in my sandbox, I always use a tool that shows me my whole commit graph visually, with all branches.

Here's a simple command line to do that, but all visual commit graph viewer have the option to show all branches:

```
git log --graph --format=oneline --all --decorate
```

If you run that after each operation, the state of things should be fairly obvious.

**PS**: My favourite git log command is actually this one, which I've aliased to `git loga` in my `.gitconfig`:

```
git log --color --graph --all --format=format:"%Cred%ad %Cgreen%h %Cblue%an%Cred%d %Creset%s" --date=short
```